# check login condition with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am new member......
Could I know what means Resource id #7?I found it when i used mysql from phpmyadmin..I want to use it to check login validation.....
This is my source code

```
mysql_connect("localhost",$dbuser,$dbpass);
                            mysql_select_db("registerform");
                            $sql2=mysql_query("select username,pass from login where username = '$user' and pass ='$pass'");
                            $row=mysql_fetch_array(($sql2));
                            if ($row['username']==$user && $row['pass']==$pass) {
                                # code...
                            echo "Login Successful!!Welcome ".$row['username'];
                            }else{
                                echo "Fail to login".$sql2;
                            }
```

Thanks you very much

Comment: I suspect it happens during login failure. You are printing the variable which contains a resource: $sql2

Comment: yes bro.I cannot check login condition.I put right data but the condition did not work.So i am printing.I cannot take data from mysql.I When I printed data , I found Resource Resource id #7.

Comment: FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which one is best for you.

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use **[PHP's built-in functions](//php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the password_hash() **[compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)**. Make sure you **[don't escape passwords](//stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so changes the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: What is the exact error message you get?

Answer (score -3):

Try to that code

```
$con=  mysql_connect("localhost",$dbuser,$dbpass,"registerform") or die("fail to connect");
$sql2=mysql_query($con,"select username,pass from login where username = '$user' and pass ='$pass'");
                        $row=mysql_fetch_array(($sql2));
                        if ($row['username']==$user && $row['pass']==$pass) {
                            # code...
                        echo "Login Successful!!Welcome ".$row['username'];
                        }else{
                            echo "Fail to login".$sql2;
                        }
```

Comment: I found this errorWarning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpDatabase2.php on line 33

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpDatabase2.php on line 34
Fail to login

Comment: This answer is poor. You're mixing mysql APIs and is very insecure. Plus you don't explain how it solves their problem.